# PHP variable in JS function

Tags: javascript, php, dns

How can write php variable in js function for tag "Free" and "Busy" for multiple language.
I'm trying more and more and isn't working.
This function is for domain checking [link](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Web-Hosting-Tools/Domain-Checker-44826.html)

```
function checkDomain (domain, tld) {
    try {
        xml['tld-' + tld].abort();
        xml['tld-' + tld].open('get', 'domena/php/checkDomain.php?domain=' + domain + '.' + tld);
        xml['tld-' + tld].onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xml['tld-' + tld].readyState == 4) {
                if (xml['tld-' + tld].responseText == 'available') {
                    el['tld-' + tld].innerHTML = '<font color="#00CC00">Free</font>';
                } else {
                    el['tld-' + tld].innerHTML = '<font color="#EE0000">Busy</font>';
                }
            } else {
                el['tld-' + tld].innerHTML = '<img src="domena/img/loader.gif" alt="Checking domenin..." />';
            }
        }
        xml['tld-' + tld].send(null);
    } catch (e) {}
}
```

Comment: Eww. At the very least, consider this: `var id = 'tld-' + tld`. Anyway, where is the "PHP variable" (or even PHP code)?

Answer (score 0):

If that's a piece of code is inside a .js file or between  tag, try doing an echo to the PHP variable, something like

```
xml['tld-' + <?php echo $tld;?>].abort();
```

Assuming $tld is the PHP var you want to insert.

Or better, you can add the PHP variable to the parameters of *checkDomain* function, for example:

```
function checkDomain (domain, tld, phpVar) {
 ...}
```

So when you call this function, you add the PHP variable value, like this:

```
onclick="checkDomain(domain, tld, <php echo $var;?>);"
```

or something like that.

This answers your question?

Cheer!

Comment: Isn't it better to put the variable as a function parameter in that case?